# How to add API dependencies on Java Ant Projects

Tags: java, gradle, ant

I haven't touched Java for almost 6 years now and as i'm trying to finish this freelance project i just realized the API from Vonage for sending and receiving SMS required to add a dependency on build file
`` Install dependencies:Add the following to `build.gradle`: ``

and this is the line that's needed `compile 'com.vonage:client:6.2.0'`
however i just realized that the the sample code from documentation points out to a bundle.gradle file that's equivalent to bundle.xml file on my Java with Ant Project, how can i properly add this to the dependency file of my project?

Comment: I strongly suggest you replace Ant with maven; see [Maven Getting Started](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/). If you insist on using Ant, the dependency manager is called [Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/).